# Regular Expression to grab relative URL in crawled Javascript

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a crawler setup with Scrapy and am trying to process links.  The problem is the links are embedded in Javascript and I am struggling to create a regular expression.  Here are 3 samples of what I am trying to process:

1. `javascript:openInIFrame('main', 'setup.phtml%3f.op%3d3800%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.menuItemRefNo=118')`
2. `javascript:window.open('overview.phtml?&.who=AAAAAAAAAAAA&.id=2', '43425235', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,maximize=yes');`
3. `javascript:openInIFrame('main', "page.phtml%3f.op%3d1499%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.ifmod%3dtest&.menuItemRefNo=7")`

The resulting relative URL for each would be between the single/double quotes:

1. `setup.phtml%3f.op%3d3800%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.menuItemRefNo=118`
2. `overview.phtml?&.who=AAAAAAAAAAAA&.id=2`
3. `page.phtml%3f.op%3d1499%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.ifmod%3dtest&.menuItemRefNo=7`

I have tried variations of `'(.*?)'` and `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1` but cannot seem to get it right.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You’ll need a couple of them – one for `window.open`, and one for `openInIFrame`.

Comment: Could I grab the quoted value based on if there is ".phtml" in there?

Comment: You tell me! =P If you always want the first single quote followed by a `phtml`, sure. `'([^']+\.phtml[^']+)'`, if you don’t need to deal with backslash escapes, then URI-decode that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
['"].*phtml.*['"]
```

http://regex101.com/r/lX6xX8/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re

url_regex = re.compile(r"(?:javascript:openInIFrame\('main',|javascript:window.open\()\s*(?:'|\")([^'\"]+)(?:'|\")")

samples = [
  "javascript:openInIFrame('main', 'setup.phtml%3f.op%3d3800%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.menuItemRefNo=118')",
  "javascript:window.open('overview.phtml?&.who=AAAAAAAAAAAA&.id=2', '43425235', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,maximize=yes');",
  "javascript:openInIFrame('main', \"page.phtml%3f.op%3d1499%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.ifmod%3dtest&.menuItemRefNo=7\")"
]

for sample in samples:
  md = url_regex.search(sample)
  if md:
    print md.group(1)
  else:
    print 'NO MATCH'
```

For me, this outputs:

```
setup.phtml%3f.op%3d3800%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.menuItemRefNo=118
overview.phtml?&.who=AAAAAAAAAAAA&.id=2
page.phtml%3f.op%3d1499%26.who%3dAAAAAAAAAAAA%26.ifmod%3dtest&.menuItemRefNo=7
```

The trick is the `([^'\"]+)`. This captures any sequence of one or more characters, so long as the character is not a double or single quote. So basically, everything up to the end of the URL string, which is precisely the URL. Note that the `\"` is only necessary because the regex itself is delimited with `"`